# SQL Dynamic WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, dynamic-sql

All, I have the following table called `Foo` which is the output of a complex `PIVOT` query

[image: Example Result Set]

I need to remove rows in this table which have (DB1, DB2, DB3) all `NULL`. To do this normally we could use something like

```
DELETE FROM Foo 
WHERE [DB1] IS NULL 
  AND [DB2] IS NULL 
  AND [DB3] IS NULL;
```

but the problem is that this code is called from C# and the columns (DB1, DB2, DB3) will change from execution-to-execution.

**How can I do this dynamically?**

Thanks for your time.

***Edit1.** I have another table `Bar` that contains the avalible `DB#` columns, so it is possible to use this table `SELECT DISTINCT ...` to get the list of columns I need in the `WHERE` clause. However, I have never done this before and am not sure where to start... Any help is appreciated.*

***Edit2. I cannot use C# in any way**. The C# code is a parser of SQL, and works with the given .sql file. This has to be done entirely in SQL.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sp_executesql` allows you to execute a SQL string built up in SQL script.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

From your bar table

```
create proc DumpFooJunk 
as
begin 
    declare @strCols nvarchar(max)
    select @strCols = N''
    select @strCols = @strCols + ' AND ' + name + ' IS NULL ' from [bar]
    select @strCols = N'DELETE FROM [foo] WHERE ' + substring(@strCols,5,LEN(@strcols))
    select @strCols
    -- exec sp_executesql @strCols
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It has given me some ideas, but there is still the issue of name here. How to get it? Also your substring starts at 5, why? The lengths of the names (i.e. DB1 etc.) are variable length. Thanks for your time.

Comment: the string starts at 5 because it is built up with an extra 'AND' at the start. If you want you can put this code in a stored procedure and call it that way - see Edit. Or do you mean how to get to the sql? just uncomment the sp_execute sql line.

Comment: It will be in an SP. But the problem remains, even with what you have provided - how do I get the column names I require. See Edit1. Again, thanks for your time.

Comment: You say the column names are in table [bar] - this builds up a list from the contents of that table.

Comment: I love this! I have to use `select @strCols = @strCols + 'AND [' + MDF + '] IS NULL ' FROM (SELECT DISTINCT MDF FROM [BarDB]..[Bar]) H`. Thanks once more!

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically build up your WHERE clause using StringBuilder, assuming the C# code is aware of the columns that should be present in the output.

Generally when you do that you would want to include parameter placeholders in the dynamic WHERE clause, and dynamically add parameters to the query as well to avoid SQL injection.  However, in this case there are no variable values.  Just concatenate the parts of the WHERE clause dynamically in C#.

Comment: For various reasons I cannot use C# to help me in anyway. The C# code is a parser for SQL and executes SQL Script files on the fly. This has to be done within the SQL script file. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from building the `WHERE` dynamically, you could also try something like this:

```
DELETE FROM Foo 
WHERE
  (0 = @db1 AND [DB1] IS NULL)
  AND (0 = @db2 AND [DB2] IS NULL)
  AND (0 = @db3 AND [DB3] IS NULL)
  -- Etc...
;
```

By setting bound parameters `@db_` to 0, you can effectively "turn-off" the corresponding `IS NULL`. So, simply set those that need to be tested to a value different from 0.

Comment: Thanks, but at this stage I can't assume the names (DB1, DB2, etc.) will be consistant (they could be anything) and there could be any number of them. Like I said in the edit I can get these names from another table `Bar` where I can `SELECT DISTINCT ...`, but I am still at a loss as to how to build the `WHERE` clause I need. Thanks for your time...

Comment: @Killercam Are you saying that you actually store field _names_ in other table? If yes, you have bigger problems ;) If no, just list all possible fields in this `WHERE`.

Comment: I have accepted the answer above. Indeed I was getting it from another table, i had no idea how to do this and @podiluska
 came up with a fantastic solution! Thanks again for your time...

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the columns by their index value if they are always at the same positions and get the column header names and then construct your SQL statement using them.

e.g.

```
string colHeader1 = (string)dr[3];
string colHeader2 = (string)dr[4];
string colHeader3 = (string)dr[5];
```